# Database design for multiple account types management system

Tags: database-design

I am trying to create multiple account types management system.

At first time, I have to types  `normal` type, and `professional` type (each type has own table, so I have two tables at this time), and new tables are coming.

Each account type has some profiles. Each profile has own table, example: table `profile_from_service_A`, table `profile_from_service_B`, ... (new profile types are coming).

When new record is inserted to `normal` (or `professional`) table, I call to service A, service B, .. to create profiles, and insert profile result to corresponding table. There is not any relation between these service about business domain.

Most used query is used for reporting , example result: `(account_id, account_type, profile_A_id, profile_A_propery_1, profile_A_propery_2, profile_B_id, profile_B_name, profile_E_id,...)`

I intend create two mapping tables. For `profile_from_service_A`, mapping table is `service_A_account_mapping` with columns: `(id_service_A, account_type, accounnt_id)`, `account_type` is `normal` or `professional` at this time.

This structure is also used for `service_B_account_mapping`, but I use `id_service_B` instead of `id_service_A`

If there is new profile, I have to create new mapping table.

Another solution: add `profile_A_id`, `profile_B_id` to `normal`, `professional` tables. Don't use mapping table anymore.

So which solution is better?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are going down the path of table explosion with resulting complicated queries.

In a relational database, you want fewer tables but more columns, fewer columns but more rows.

Applying this mantra: your two types of accounts should be one `accounts` table with a `type` column. You could have two child tables to store data specific to each type of account if there would otherwise be too many `null` columns. But if there are only one or two such attributes I would personally add them as nullable columns and add a constraint something like:

```
 alter table accounts
   add check (type = 'normal' and pro_attribute is null or type = 'professional' and pro_attribute is not null);
```

where `pro_attribute` is the name of an attribute that only applies to professional accounts.

This could be simplified to:

```
alter table accounts
  add check ((type = 'normal') = (pro_attribute is null));
```

but that's not clearer.

Then for your profiles, you need to apply the same pattern: One `profiles` table with a `service` column. If individual services have different attributes you can store them in their own child tables.

As far as the relationship to services: it sounds like each `account` has one `profile` for each service that exists. In this case I would create the `profiles` table with columns `account_id` (foreign key to `accounts`), `service` (or `service_id` as a foreign key to a `services` table) and any attributes you need for that particular service for that particular account.